# Django translations does not work

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, language-translation

I'm trying to get Django's translation system to work, following the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/).

Here are my two views (one for direct output, one for template), neither one works.

```
def home(request):        
    output = _("hello") # (lazy)
    return HttpResponse(output)

def with_template(request):
    return render(request, 'translation_template.html')
```

here is the template file for the second view :

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<p>{% trans 'hello' %}</p>
{% language 'tr' %}
<p>{% trans 'hello' %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
{% language 'tr-TR' %}
<p>{% trans 'hello' %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
{% endblock %}
```

in my settings file, I added the following: (may add parts from before if requested)

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'    
# also tried LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr'  and LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-TR'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

"""
# tried but didn't work
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
)
"""
LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'locale'), )
LANGUAGES = (
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

after saving these, I executed in the terminal :

```
python ./manage.py makemessages -l tr
```

then edited the newly created `myproject/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` to have this :

```
msgid "hello"
msgstr "merhaba"
```

then executed

```
python ./manage.py compilemessages
```

and restarted the server. the terminal commands show no error, but when I load the views, none of the "hello"s are translated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

### Edit:

I found a suspicious code in en/../django.po, probably not relevant, but maybe it is. This is the very beginning of the file. The fuzzy (empty->empty) translation, could it be the problem?

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
```

Comment: Negative score in less than 1 min. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your browser is requesting the Turkish page? Try printing the current language in your template for debugging: `{% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as current_lang %}` and `{{ current_lang.code }}`

Comment: @halilpazarlama, have you included `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware`  in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Comment: @Anzel yes. @ Selcuk it says `en`. I also added a translation for English, "eng_hello" but it doesn't apply.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, try change your browser encoding/locale etc. to Turkish and see if it picks up the locale accordingly

Comment: Do you have lines starting with "fuzzy" in your .po file? If yes, remove them.

Comment: No they are not fuzzy. Shouldn't my trial of `{% language 'tr' %}` be doing this for me? **Edit** : I changed Chrome's settings to Turkish, @Selcuk's code shows `tr` this time, but again, no translation..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I solved my issue. In my case, the problem was with the `LOCALE_PATHS` definition in settings.py.

I tested it in the view by :

```
from TranslationTest import settings
return HttpResponse(settings.LOCALE_PATHS)
```

It was showing `home/myProjects/TranslationTest/TranslationTest/locale`, however `makemessages` was producing the files in `home/myProjects/TranslationTest/locale`

so I changed my settings as follows :

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__))
LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'locale'), )
```

and now it works.

But I still wonder, why didn't `makemessages` understand that it should create the files in the `LOCALE_PATHS` specificed by settings.py?

In my understanding, it always produces the locale files in SITE_ROOT/locale, so we should always set LOCALE_PATHS to this? If this is a default, why set it at all? I would appreciate further information on this issue.

Thanks for all the help !

Comment: Print out settings.LOCALE_PATHS did help me solve this problem. the LOCALE_PATHS should include all 'locale' folder in the project. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This happens if you have the locale middleware activated. By so doing, I think your session local depends on your browser locale.

if you comment the locale middleware, it should be working as expected.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 7):

and keep in mind if your language has a country in it e.g. fa-IR, in your settings file you must add:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-IR'
```

but when you want to call makemessages command you should change `-` to `_`:

```
makemessages -l fa_IR
```

Comment: Related to this, from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations): `In all cases the name of the directory containing the translation is expected to be named using locale name notation. E.g. de, pt_BR, es_AR, etc.`

Answer (score 7):

I tried almost all of the offered solutions above without any success. Then I realised that I forgot to run `compilemessages` after `makemessages` command. So make sure you run:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

After running makemessages. What the `compilemessages` command does is it converts `.po` files to `.mo` files in your locale directories. This is needed because `.mo` files are the only files that gettext can understand. Without `.mo` files translation won't work, which was the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, with Django 3.2 this issue is still present.
In my case, I have the following setup:

```
C:.
├───documents
├───project
│   ├───apps
│   │   ├───accounts
│   │   │   ├───...
│   │   ├───common
│   │   │   ├───...
│   │   └───...
│   ├───locale
│   │   └───it
│   │       └───LC_MESSAGES
│   └───...
└───tests
```

The settings file is set in this way:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(Path(__file__).resolve().parent, "locale"),
]

LANGUAGES = [
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('it', _('Italian')),
]
```

The trick is in the definition of LOCALE_PATHS. Django-admin is in some way not synced with the Django environment.

Comment: thanks! I was having issues with my transaltions not appearing. This locale_path worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to remind something that cause me a tiny problem and it was that I should change language of browser(from options).
However I did everything completely but I couldn't see the translated texts.
And by the way I didn't want to use any specific url for seeing the translation.

Answer (score 0):

For me commenting en line works OK

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'uk'
LANGUAGES = (
('uk', _('Ukrainian')),
# ('en', _('English')),
)
```

no locale folder in a project root, no custom LOCALE_PATHS

Answer (score 0):

adding the local middle ware to the django middle ware  worked for me `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to read this [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

TLDR;

The locale middleware decides the user language in the following order:

1. `i18n_patterns` function in your root `URLconf`
2. Failing that, it looks for a cookie set by the `LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME` setting
3. Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header sent by your **Browser**
4. Failing that, it uses the global `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting

In my case I followed a tutorial and I didn't had a clue what why my language was not changing.

I was already done with the locale folder where i had all the strings for both of languages translated and i had already setup the `LOCALE_PATH` and other stuffs correctly.

So for testing i changed the `LANGUAGE_CODE` to display the text in hindi but i was not aware of the language precedence stuff.

i had set the following in my settings

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('hi', _('Hindi')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi'
```

So what was happening was that i had no cookie that specified the language so the precedence fell for the browsers default language passed in http header.

So it never came to the  `LANGUAGE_CODE` in my settings and the language in the `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` was set to en.

So for solving this issue i set the cookie to take precedence before my browser

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import translation
user_language = 'hi'
translation.activate(user_language)
response = HttpResponse(...)
response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, user_language)
```

I took this from here [Explicitly setting the active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language)

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Candy Translate](https://candytranslate.com) instead of Django native translations module. It is much easier, do not require to set up the middleware and basically does most of the work for you.
It also allows you to manage the translations in the excel file which comes handy when you are sending the texts to the translators.

It comes with some limitations but for all my websites it was just enough and achieved much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JavaScript code in a file inside the static folder(you need to run the collectstatic command) in order to the `djangojs.po` to be generated. Because Django by default look at this destination when dealing with JS files.